# advanced query function follow up a data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importdata

I have a Google sheets where i’m using a simple query function to import data from another Google sheets (**SPREADSHEET 01**)

**SPREADSHEET 01** contains:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NAME 01 | PRODUCT 01 | CITY 01 | ✓ |
| NAME 02 | PRODUCT 02 | CITY 02 | X |
| NAME 03 | PRODUCT 03 | CITY 03 | ✓ |

---

**SPREADSHEET 02**

I’M DOING THE FOLLOWING:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(“SPREADSHEET 01 URL”,”Sheet1!A1:E”),”SELECT \* WHERE Col4=’✓'”)`

THE RESULT:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NAME 01 | PRODUCT 01 | CITY 01 | ✓ |
| NAME 03 | PRODUCT 03 | CITY 03 | ✓ |

---

LET’S SAY I’M DOING A CHECK TO EACH RESULT IN AN NEW COLUMN (column 05)

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NAME 01 | PRODUCT 01 | CITY 01 | ✓ | Done |
| NAME 03 | PRODUCT 03 | CITY 03 | ✓ | Done |

---

NOW IF THE ROW 2 IN **SPREADSHEET 01** TURNS THE “X” TO “✓” WILL RUINS MY CHECKING PROGRESS AND BECOME LIKE THIS:

---

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NAME 01 | PRODUCT 01 | CITY 01 | ✓ | Done |
| NAME 02 | PRODUCT 02 | CITY 02 | ✓ | Done |
| NAME 03 | PRODUCT 03 | CITY 03 | ✓ |  |

---

*** AS YOU CAN SEE THE 2nd ROW WHERE column 5 CONTAINS “DONE” IT’S ACTUALLY RETURNS TO THE 3rd ROW

---

MY QUESTION IS: IS THERE A FUNCTION WHERE IT CAN FIX THIS ISSUE?
AND SHOWS THE RESULTS LIKE THIS:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NAME 01 | PRODUCT 01 | CITY 01 | ✓ | Done |
| NAME 02 | PRODUCT 02 | CITY 02 | ✓ |  |
| NAME 03 | PRODUCT 03 | CITY 03 | ✓ | Done |

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

I TRIED MANY FORMULAS AND FUNCTIONS YET I HAVEN'T FOUND ANY SOLUTION!

Comment: **For clarification**: 1) SPREADSHEET 02-Formula = `Sheet1!A1:E` but only shows output for Columns A-D. What is output in Column E for this query?  **Comment**: if you are adding "Done" manually in SPREADSHEET 02, you need to link it to a unique value in the output so that the manual data moves with the unique value.

Comment: Related questions: [Align imported Data with manually added data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73385545/1330560) and [Is it possible to "fix" cells similar to the page break at Word?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75593409/1330560) (don't let the "Word" reference throw you off, it covers your issue exactly).

Comment: Yes, Iam adding "Done" manually in SPREADSHEET 02.
How i can link it to a unique value in the output if the output is changing (or might change) in the SPREADSHEET 01.
+

Comment: None of this is new or original. There are dozens of examples of this same scenario and many offer solutions; in each case, the solution is the same - create a unique key/ID on SPREADSHEET01. player0 provides a succinct answer- `you will need to rethink your approach and implement some supporting system like IDs. then you can use VLOOKUP to match both datasets based on ID`  For a more detailed discussion of the issues @Rubén has a good description in [Align imported data with manual input data in a Google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57947542/1330560).

Comment: Hi, @Tedinoz 
From what i understand he used IDs and VLOOKUP in the 1st file and then he imported to the 2nd file using lookup formula (VLOOKUP / INDEX-MATCH) to get the related records. is that right?
If so, How i'm gonna link it to a unique value in the output so that the manual data moves with the unique value?.
Thank you

Comment: A unique ID doesn't exist in a vacuum. It is related to a given set, so if that data set exists in two sheets, then the ID is accessible in both sheets. The most important element of that answer is: `you will need to rethink your approach`.